# What Excel Formula will count the number of responses which match a condition but only once for that person?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to count survey responses. I would like to be able to answer how many people have ever answered the question with the answer value "1". However, people have answered the survey multiple times. If they have answered the survey three times, and said "1" the first time, "2" the Second, and "1" the third, that should yield a 1 for that person. 
So the for the following data:

```
JM  27/03/2015  2
DR  10/04/2015  2
AD  24/04/2015  2
DR  15/05/2015  1
AD  29/05/2015  1
AD  20/06/2015  2
AD  04/07/2015  1
DR  18/07/2015  1
DR  31/07/2015  2
JM  15/08/2015  2
JM  22/08/2015  2
```

The correct formula will result in a "2"
Because DR&AD have both answered a "1" at some point, whereas JM has only answered "2" 
I have tried a lot of options, but can not seem to get it right. Each person must only be counted once, but many have answered the survey multiple times. 
Any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script/formula writing service. Please share with us what formula you have already tried and we will attempt to help you find the problem.

Comment: I believe this already has [an answer on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18588144/4497791).

Answer (score 0):

This is something much easier to do in Access, but assuming you can make an additional column you can set `D1 =IF(C1=1,A1,"")` and drag/copy it for all records. At this point, the function

```
=IF(COUNTIF(D1:D11,"")=0,
 SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(D1:D11,D1:D11,0),MATCH(D1:D11,D1:D11,0))>0,1)),
 SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(D1:D11,D1:D11,0),MATCH(D1:D11,D1:D11,0))>0,1))-1)
```

in a cell will return your desired value.

Eirikdaude found a much simpler solution than the three line code in a linked solution.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D1:D11<>"")/COUNTIF(D1:D11,D1:D11&""))
```

is far simpler!

Comment: Or just use the solution in the answer I linked: `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A100<>"")/COUNTIF(A2:A100,A2:A100&""))`, requires less fiddling around.

Comment: Good catch, I forgot `SUMPRODUCT` was a function available in Excel. That's far more efficient!